# Why is hyphenation not tried for words followed by em-dash?

Tags: tex-core, punctuation, hyphenation

Consider the following `mystory.tex`:

```
\tolerance=10000 \hsize=.7in
\leavevmode\nobreak\hskip0pt Drofnats---or ``R. J.,''
\end
```

This is the log:

```
(mystory.tex
Overfull \hbox (17.41133pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--3
[] \tenrm Drofnats---|
[1] )
```

This is the output:

[image]

Now change `mystory.tex` by adding space between "Drofnats" and "---".

This is the log:

```
(mystory.tex
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 2--3
[] \tenrm Drof-

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 2--3
\tenrm nats ---or
[1] )
```

This is the output:

[image]

As far as I understand typographic rules dictate that we must use em-dash like `word1---word2`. Do the typographic rules also prohibit hyphenation of `word1`? If not, why hyphenation is not tried by default?

Comment: hyphenation is not tried in words containing an explicit hyphen, or ligatures ending in a hyphen, you can use a macro that surrounds the `---` with 0pt space if you want to allow hyphenation

Comment: Is anyone even using `word---word` anymore? I though even the British use `word -- word` these days

Comment: @daleif or something like `\,---\,`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 1) "`\,---\,`" - but `\,` works only in math mode. 2) Using `\kern0pt` before `---` will add hyphenation to "Drofnats" without allowing break before `---` (as by default); in contrast, using `\hskip0pt` before `---` will add hyphenation to "Drofnats" by allowing break before `---`. 3) Do you know where to find exact typographic standards? (like using spaces around `---` or using `,` before closing `''` etc)

Comment: The em dash is often used without spaces (Chigago style) but I find munch more readable a em dash with spaces (Associated Press style) that moreover avoid this problem.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko `\,` works in latex, in plain you could use an equivalent hskip, there are no definite standards, different publishers have different rules about dashes and spaces (google for emdash  there are hundreds of guides all in disagreement:-)

Comment: @daleif **Off-topic:** `Is anyone even using word---word anymore?` :) I never understood why there are no spaces surrounding the `---`.

Comment: Philosophically, I think the answer to this question is that TeX tries to avoid hyphenation as much as possible; it only inserts unobjectionable/unsurprising hyphens and only when actually needed. The user who wants better-looking paragraphs can (after decreasing `\tolerance` if necessary) decide how best to deal with their underfull/overfull boxes, by adding hyphenation to certain words, or rewriting, or... From this perspective, hyphenation in words around dashes, like hyphenation in words that already contain hyphens, can be undesirable and best avoided if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the TeXbook, page 286, last but one bullet point:

> ⟨letter⟩, ⟨otherchar⟩, `\char`⟨8-bit number⟩, ⟨chardef token⟩,
>   `\noboundary`.
>   The most common commands of all are the character commands that tell
>   TeX to append a character to the current horizontal
>   list, using the current font.
>   [...]
>   In unrestricted horizontal mode, a
>   ‘`\discretionary{}{}{}`’ item is appended after a character whose code is
>   the `\hyphenchar` of its font, or after a ligature formed from a sequence
>   that ends with such a character.

Since `---` is a ligature that ends with the `\hyphenchar` of the current font, that's usually the hyphen, a `\discretionary{}{}{}` item is automatically appended and TeX never hyphenates words containing a `\discretionary` item (see page 454, end of last but one double dangerous bend).